# Invalid temp images directory in chart handler configuration

Tags: asp.net, iis, highcharts

I am using highchart and I am getting this error only when I run my website on IIS server in intranet network. Instead it works fine in the development server (visual studio 2012)

> Invalid temp images directory in chart handler configuration
>   [c:\TempImageFiles]. Please edit the web.config file. The
>   CharImageHandler key, Dir value must point to a valid directory. The
>   directory is required for temporary image storage when storage mode
>   equals file system.

**Stack trace**

```
[DirectoryNotFoundException: Invalid temp images directory in chart handler configuration [c:\TempImageFiles\]. Please edit the web.config file. The CharImageHandler key, Dir value must point to a valid directory. The directory is required for temporary image storage when storage mode equals file system.]
   System.Web.UI.DataVisualization.Charting.ChartHttpHandlerSettings.Inspect() +1426397
   System.Web.UI.DataVisualization.Charting.ChartHttpHandlerSettings.ParseParams(String parameters) +1352
   System.Web.UI.DataVisualization.Charting.ChartHttpHandler.get_Settings() +197
   System.Web.UI.DataVisualization.Charting.ChartHttpHandler.InitializeControllerFile() +51
   System.Web.UI.DataVisualization.Charting.ChartHttpHandler.EnsureInitialized(Boolean hardCheck) +357
   System.Web.UI.DataVisualization.Charting.Chart.get_CurrentImageLocation() +50
   System.Web.UI.DataVisualization.Charting.Chart.Render(HtmlTextWriter writer) +345
   System.Web.UI.Control.RenderControlInternal(HtmlTextWriter writer, ControlAdapter adapter) +150
   System.Web.UI.Control.RenderChildrenInternal(HtmlTextWriter writer, ICollection children) +249
   System.Web.UI.Control.RenderControlInternal(HtmlTextWriter writer, ControlAdapter adapter) +150
   System.Web.UI.Control.RenderChildrenInternal(HtmlTextWriter writer, ICollection children) +249
   System.Web.UI.HtmlControls.HtmlForm.RenderChildren(HtmlTextWriter writer) +395
   System.Web.UI.HtmlControls.HtmlContainerControl.Render(HtmlTextWriter writer) +49
   System.Web.UI.Control.RenderControlInternal(HtmlTextWriter writer, ControlAdapter adapter) +150
   System.Web.UI.Control.RenderChildrenInternal(HtmlTextWriter writer, ICollection children) +249
   System.Web.UI.Control.RenderControlInternal(HtmlTextWriter writer, ControlAdapter adapter) +150
   System.Web.UI.Control.RenderChildrenInternal(HtmlTextWriter writer, ICollection children) +249
   System.Web.UI.Page.Render(HtmlTextWriter writer) +40
   System.Web.UI.Control.RenderControlInternal(HtmlTextWriter writer, ControlAdapter adapter) +150
   System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestMain(Boolean includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint) +5363
```

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Previously it was like this in `web.config`

```
<add key="ChartImageHandler" value="storage=file;timeout=20; dir=c:\TempImageFiles/;" />
```

I removed the directory location

```
<add key="ChartImageHandler" value="storage=file;timeout=20;" />
```

And the problem solved.

Comment: bummi you will get your answer once you see the comments under @giammin's answers and his edits....his answer was previously not helpful to me. 1st i commented then i wrote down my own answer. it took me while to post mine and the problem was solved by my self. He just edited his answer inorder to help others.

Comment: Any idea what causes this? Both servers have c:\TempImageFiles, one server requires the `dir` attribute and one does not.

Answer (score 6):

Check if that folder exists on your server and give read/write permission to the user of the application pool your site is running for that folder.

Or you can simple move that temp folder inside the site root Es: "~/temp" and configure highchart to use that folder.

Or you can change your ChartImageHandler from

```
<add key="ChartImageHandler" value="storage=file;timeout=20;dir=c:\TempImageFiles\;" />
```

To

```
<add key="ChartImageHandler" value="storage=file;timeout=20;" />
```

So he will use the default windows temp directory

Comment: How am I suppose to do this?

Comment: check the user application pool of your site with iismanager. then rightclick on that folder and go to security tab

Comment: Nop..still the same problem

Comment: @Saumil ok, I wrote it down to help others with same problem

Comment: If you remove the directory, the iis user for the application must also have permission to the default directory. In my case, I don't want the iis user to have read/write permission in the default directory...so I created a new directory on the server and gave the iis user r/w permission. Then changed the key value in web.config (or in iis application config) to include `dir=c:\path\to\safe\directory\;`

Answer (score 0):

Only Removed (`dir=c:\TempImageFiles\;`) the directory location from the `web.config`

```
<add key="ChartImageHandler" value="storage=file;timeout=20;" />
```

and its work...!