# ASP.NET Chart crashing on server side

Tags: c#, asp.net

EDIT: After debugging and testing it was confirmed to be an issue with the Chart, not the panel resize.

I have this on the control's page:

```
<td><asp:Button ID="btn_Details" runat="server" Text="Show Details" OnClick="btn_Details_Click" /></td>
```

The code behind the scenes is as follows:

```
protected void btn_Details_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    ToggleDetails();
}
void ToggleDetails()
{
    if ((bool)ViewState["bShowingDetails"] == true)
    {
        Panel1.Height = 60;
        btn_Details.Text = "Show Details";
        ViewState["bShowingDetails"] = false;
        ChartPanel.Visible = false;
    }
    else
    {
        Panel1.Height = 400;
        btn_Details.Text = "Hide Details";
        ViewState["bShowingDetails"] = true;
        UpdateGraph();
        ChartPanel.Visible = true;
    }
}
```

The control is contained on an `UpdatePanel` on the main page. I have other elements on that control that are updating without any issues. But for some reason the button click handler is not re-sizing as expected. If I add code into the handler to hide the control, it will disappear. So I know the handler is running and not throwing any exceptions.

Any ideas why the control won't resize on the server?

Images of what it does on local machine:
[image: Prior to click]
[image: Expanded]

EDIT: 
The console output is spitting out this error when I try to click:

> Sys.WebForms.PageRequestManagerServerErrorException:
>   Sys.WebForms.PageRequestManagerServerErrorException: An unknown error
>   occurred while processing the request on the server. The status code
>   returned from the server was: 500

Comment: God I hate UpdatePanels. Worst idea Microsoft ever came up with. Are there any js errors in the console?

Comment: I take it there is a better way to do on screen updating? I just recently decided to dive into asp after living in the WPF world for years. I don't see any errors in the console, but it also works when I run it locally. Is there a way to see errors from the server side when I am running it from that end?

Comment: Admittedly this is a straw-grasp, but any chance your server is running a different version of ASP.NET from that on your local box? There were some breaking changes for UpdatePanels between some of the versions of ASP.NET...shot in the dark...

Comment: The problem is that the UpdatePanel was a massive hack thrown together by microsoft in response to the Ruby on rails type frameworks that could do ajax simply. You can do this better using a framework like jQuery and webmethods (or better yet [MVC](http://www.asp.net/mvc)), but that does involve more work if your used to the old postback pattern.

Comment: Ok, this doesn't answer your question, but, If your just starting to learn ASP.Net I would recommend skipping webforms altogether and jumping straight to MVC. Webforms' days are numbered. [This article on Katana](http://www.asp.net/aspnet/overview/owin-and-katana/an-overview-of-project-katana) goes into the mentality of each framework quite well and why the decision was made to develop MVC in response to exactly this type of problem

Comment: @DavidW Yes they are both running 4.5.

Comment: @Liam I will look into MVC, thank you for the information. No use learning something that is going away.

Comment: @JeremyK Oh, well, as I said, it was a long shot. I think you're back to seeing if there are bizarre javascript errors when you run it from the server; maybe it's blocking what it thinks is some xss issue when run from the server.

Comment: @Liam After programming in WebForms for years, and finally trying code-first entity framework MVC on a small project recently, it makes me wish I'd picked up MVC a *long* time ago. WebForms is going to survive through ASP.NET 4.6, but 5.0 looks MVC all the way.

Comment: @DavidW where would I look to find the errors on the server side? Hate asking simple questions like that. But I am honestly not sure where to look on IIS or wherever

Comment: Looked into C:\inetpub\logs\LogFiles but dont see any errors just lots of POSTS and GETs

Comment: @JeremyK Javascript errors would occur on your client within your broswer. You can open up IE dev tools by hitting F12 and running the site (and clicking the button); errors normally consumed will show up there.

Comment: These things are a pig to debug. Download and fire up [fiddler](http://www.telerik.com/fiddler) is the server returning a valid (HTTP 200) code? Check the event viewer on the server does that give any errors? Basically if it works in x but not in y then something is different about y. Try and work though each difference and hopefully you find the *magic rune* that's missing

Comment: Thanks guys. Looks like I am getting an uncaught server error code 500 (Sys.WebForms.PageRequestManagerServerErrorException). Going to look into adding more error handling to try and figure out what is causing it.

Comment: FWIW, (and you may already know this) a 500 is an "Internal Server Error" which is a generic response for a fairly low-level crash on the server side based on whatever was submitted. Good luck.

Comment: There should be an error (if your not handling it yourself) in the event viewer of the server with a full stack trace from this. Will likely point you at the problem.

Comment: @Liam that helped me figure it out. Had to do with the Chart and some temp image folder.. "TempImageFiles"  What a pain. Just made the folder it was looking for and problem went away. Glad I know to check event viewer. Thanks guys, appreciate the help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out the Chart was looking for a folder on the server that did not exist. Once I created the folder on the C drive the error went away.

See this question: [Invalid temp images directory in chart handler configuration](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20397796/invalid-temp-images-directory-in-chart-handler-configuration)